# Receiving a group list in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I have a table with data like

```
UserID Item
1  apple
1  banana
2  apple
3  grapefruit
```

and want a list like

```
1  apple, banana
2  apple
3  grapefruit
```

as a result.

I don't know how to search for this, as I lack the proper vocab :(

Solutions or searchterms greatly appreciated,

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not really that clear what you're trying to do.  Can you edit this, and provide the schema of the table, then put the records in like a csv format here or something?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT UserID, GROUP_CONCAT(Item)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY UserID
```

[This page of the MySQL Reference Manual further explains the functionality of GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: How did u conclude this solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
select userid, group_concat(item SEPARATOR ',')
from your_table
group by userid
```

See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afa42/1) Example

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a spece after the comma :)

```
select UserID, group_concat(Item order by Item separator ', ') from t
group by UserID
```

You can change the ordering criteria of the group_concat. In this case I'm ordering alphabetically by Item, as it seems that's the order you applied to the results.

Check the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html) to see how to use GROUP_CONCAT.